# how can I use images from buttons on a form I have no control over the HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to swap out the default form buttons on an HTML form with images, but I can not change the HTML as it is being returned by a SOAP service

any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("button").after("<input type=\"image\" />").remove();
```

Does this work for you?

- [`after`](http://api.jquery.com/after/)
- [`remove`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

Answer (score 1):

Add your own CSS file to the html with jquery

```
$('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css" type="text/css" />');
```

In that stylesheet do whatever with the buttons whatever you need to do with them (display none, replace img not sure what you mean with swap out)

Comment: by swap out, I mean, display images instead of form buttons

Comment: There you can use the stylesheet for. Give the buttons a bg image, change the height, width ect

Answer (score 0):

```
//remove all submit buttons
$("input:submit").remove();
```

OR (don't know exactly what you want to do):

```
$("input:submit").attr("type", "image").addClass("myImageBtn");
```

EDIT: nevermind, the last solution is not allowed by your browser.

Comment: I want to replace the buttons with images